# How good is Wall Street Survivor for learning about investing?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I'm a recent graduate and I would really like to start learning about investing and want some experience in the stock market without actually risking any money.

As an avid fan of fantasy football I thought it would be fun if I could spend fake money on real stocks and earn fake money based on the actual stock market's performance.

Is Wall Street Survivor (http://www.wallstreetsurvivor.com/) anything like what I'm looking for? Does it pull data from the real stock market? Is there something better? Can anybody comment on how close it is to real investing?

Comment: Doesn't hurt to try. Nothing will ever come to real investing, when you loose you loose real money and when you gain you gain real money. But what you can take from the game can come in handy.

Comment: @DumbCoder since the OP is just now starting, using a demo account is more than wise so he can get some experience and get the ball rolling with the (inevitable) starting losses be theoretic only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I've never used Wall Street Survivor, I took a look over the marketing materials and I've seen multiple similar contests run among investment interns also just out of college.  I see some good here and some bad.

First off, I love interactive web-based tutorials.  I've used one to learn the syntax of a new programming language and I find the instant feedback and the ability to work at your own pace very useful.  The reviews seem to say that Wall Street Survivor is a good way to learn the basics of how trading stocks works and the lingo.  Also, it seems pretty fun which [I've found helps a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Typing_of_the_Dead).

Wall Street Survivor will hopefully teach you that there are many real stock markets and that they may have somewhat different prices and they likely take the real and timely data from a single market.

Wall Street Survivor also frightens me.  The big problem that I see with interns running similar contests is that the market is extremely random over short to medium periods of time.  An intern can make an awful portfolio or even pick stocks at random and still win the contest.  These interns know a lot about the randomness in markets already so they don't believe they are trading geniuses because they won a contest, I'm not sure there is much to temper this view on this web-site.

Also, while Wall Street Survivor teaches you about trading it doesn't appear to teach you about investing.  The website appears to encourage short term views and [changing positions a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churning_%28finance%29) and doesn't seem to simulate the full trading costs (including fees) that would eat away at the gains of a individual investor that trades that much.  It gives some help with longer term thinking like diversification, but also seems to encourage trading that makes Wall Street Survivor more money, but are likely detrimental to the user.

I would say have fun with Wall Street Survivor. Let it teach you some things about trading, but don't give the site much if any money.  At the same time, pick up a copy of short book called "[A Random Walk Down Wall Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Random_Walk_Down_Wall_Street)" and start learning about investing at the same time.  Feel free to come back to Stack Exchange with questions along the way.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, wall street survivor is good but when it comes to learning the stock markets from Europe, Beat wall street is the game to be playing. You can try it out for your self here on http://beatwallstreet.equitygameonline.com/ It is easy to use and there are monthly prizes available to winners, such as Ipads, Iphones and students who play it the game can win internships at top investment banks and brokers

Comment: There's an impressive number of spelling and grammar mistakes on that page for a supposedly legitimate enterprise ...

Comment: wow, is there, in which language?

Comment: oh i see what you mean now, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

I find this site to be really poor for the virtual play portion, especially the options league.  After you place a trade, you can't tell what you actually traded.  The columns for Exp and type are blank.  I have had better luck with OptionsXpress virtual trader.  Although they have recently changed their criteria for a non funded accounts and will only keep them active for 90 days.  I know the cboe has a paper trading platform but I haven't tried it out yet.